# How to ignore constant changes to existing 'build/' directory?

Tags: git

I have already built my (React in my case) app many times with

```
npm run build
```

so I have an exiting build directory with the result.
The problem is that every time I do a build I get a bunch of changes showing up in git that are from the build in `build/` and not from the code development process itself.
In addition, the `build/` directory already existed so by ignoring it now I may be left with an old version that is out of date in my source control.  If I actually remove the directory that will show as a big change and then it will be replaced again when I do the build.  What to do?

Answer (score 0):

#### Removing existing directories that change a lot can be confusing in Git

This can be a little confusing when you are learning Git, and even when you know have the details it can be a little convoluted.

One option is to not track changes to the build directory as follows:

- `rm build/ #` Note, you could also move (i.e. save) the build directory elsewhere in case you can't `build` again
- `git commit -m"removed build directory"`
- edit `.gitignore` adding `build/`
- `git add .gitignore`
- `git commit -m"ignore build directories"`
- `npm run build` # Now build directory is recreated but will be ignored now and in the future by git

  (or move the directories back from step 1 if you can't do a `build`)